# Send a custom parameter (userId) in inApp Purchase iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I want to send the `userId` of my application with the `inApp Purchase` so that the `transaction ID` that I get after successful `inApp purchase`, I be able to know the `userId` of the user who purchased that product from Apple's server using the transaction ID. Is this possible ? or something related to it ?

Comment: Take a look at `applicationUsername` https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentRequest_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPayment/applicationUsername

Comment: It says that its a read-only property :\

Comment: Use SKMutablePayment. `SKMutablePayment* payment = [SKMutablePayment paymentWithProduct:product]; payment.applicationUsername = @"your_user_id";`

Comment: My IA Item is consumable, I dont want to make any restoring thing. If i do these steps in my consumable IAP, how will I be able to see this with the transaction ID on the apple's end ?